# Does there exist a probability density function?

Tags: probability

Does there exist a probability density function of the form $b \ e^{ax}$ where $a>0$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: For a suitable probability space (here: measurable subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$) it is indeed possible that $\int_A be^{ax}\,\mathrm dx=1$

Comment: @nrpeterson What are YOUR thoughts on the question? What would you suggest? What have you tried?

Comment: I just want to know why most of the density functions are of the form $\lambda e^{\lambda x}$ not in the form I asked?

Answer (score 2):

Note $\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^xdx=1$. All you have to do is 'tune' the values for $a$ and $b$.